# Discriminating Union Types by unique property

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

There is a type with unique property (method)

```
type Actions = {
  method: "connections",
  request: number,
  response: number,
} | {
  method: "delete",
  request: string,
  response: string,
}
```

I want to make a function which will accept (request) and process (response) values of type based on the unique field.

```
type Fn = <A extends Actions>(a: Pick<A, 'method' | 'request'>) => Pick<A, 'method' | 'response'>;
```

But when I call the implementation, e.g.:

```
const x = fn({ method: "connections", request: 10 })
x.response
```

I get following type for response field

```
string | number
```

How can I narrow the type without further checking the method property? (Likely changing the Fn type)

Comment: There are quite a number of approaches to this; the one recommended in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NV7gxm).  I could write that up as an answer if it meets your needs more than the existing answers; if you want that, let me know (if you reply, please mention @jcalz to notify me)

Comment: @jcalz That is a good working answer too. For the sake of clarity, I would just suggest to have a shared [Keys type](https://tsplay.dev/mqeEJm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of the problem is that the function call

```
fn({ method: "connections", request: 10 })
```

is typed:

```
const fn: <Actions>(a: Pick<Actions, "method" | "request">)
```

That is, the type parameter `A` is inferred with `Actions`, the union of all possible `Action` types, not the particular `Action` type being invoked. This has ramifications well beyond a vague return type. For instance:

```
fn({ method: "connections", request: "weird" })
```

will compile just fine, because the type of request, `A['request']`, resolves to `Action['request']`, which is `number | string`, which admits `"weird"` ...

I don't know a way to fix this with the action specification you have provided, but if we describe the possible actions like this:

```
type Actions = {
  connections: {
    request: number,
    response: number,
  },
  delete: {
    request: string,
    response: string,
  }
}
```

the following works as intended:

```
type Fn = <M extends keyof Actions>(a: {method: M, request: Actions[M]['request']}) => {method: M, response: Actions[M]['response']};

declare const fn: Fn;

fn({ method: "connections", request: "weird" }); // Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
const x = fn({ method: "connections", request: 42 }); // ok
x.response // type number
```

Comment: It is weird it is omitting 'extends' and assume all types, not only the particular one. Also I put to `type Actions` a `method` property and then try

`type Fn = <M extends keyof Actions>(a: Pick<Actions[M], 'method' | 'request'>) => Pick<Actions[M], 'method' | 'response'>;`

which should aim for precise type by key as your solution, but gives union types for response.